# Getting the same post on my related post

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories

I am displaying the related products on my single.php page.

I am getting two issues.

1. When I am on a single page I am getting the same post on my related post.
2. I have to show the max 4 post on my related section. If I have 3 posts related to the same category then display only 3

I tried the below code.

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
    $cat_ids = array();
    $categories = get_the_category($post_id);
    if(!empty($categories) && is_wp_error($categories)):
        foreach ($categories as $category):
            array_push($cat_ids, $category->term_id);
        endforeach;
    endif;
    $current_post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $query_args = array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'blogs_cat',
        'category__in'   => $cat_ids,
        'post_type'      => $current_post_type,
        'post_not_in'    => array($post_id),
        'posts_per_page'  => '4',
        'order' => 'DEC',
     );
    $related_cats_post = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    if($related_cats_post->have_posts()):
        echo '<div class="relatedPostWrapper"><ul>';
         while($related_cats_post->have_posts()): $related_cats_post->the_post();
          echo '<li>
                    <a href="'.get_permalink($related_cats_post->ID).'">
                        <div class="d-table">
                            <div class="relatedpost-img d-table-cell">
                            <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($related_cats_post->ID).'">
                            </div>
                            <div class="relatedpost-title d-table-cell">
                                 '.get_the_title($related_cats_post->ID).'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul></div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
     endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        'post_not_in'    => array($post_id),
```

Here is your problem, and there are two of them:

1. The parameter key is misspelt
2. There's a massive performance hit that can be easily avoided

#### Using the Correct Key

It should be `post__not_in` not `post_not_in`. This will restore the desired behaviour, but with a huge performance hit that gets heavier as the size of the posts table increases.

This is because you should always ask the database for what you want, never ask it for what you do not want. MySQL will respond to this by creating a brand new copy of the posts table that doesn't have that post, then performing the query on the new table, then discarding it.

*But there's a simple alternative*

### Fixing the Performance

The solution is simple, ask for 5 posts instead of 4 and skip the post you don't want. Excluding posts in PHP is almost instant in comparison.

For example:

```php
$q = new \WP_Query( [ 'posts_per_page' => 5 ] );
$counter = 0;
$post_to_skip = 1;
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() {
        $q->the_post();
        if ( get_the_ID() === $post_to_skip ) {
            continue; // skip
        }
        if ( ++$counter === 4 ) {
            break; // only 4 posts
        }
        // ... display post
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and valuable information. Yes, I have to use post__not_in instated of post_not_in.  I'll try my second option which is in your answer.

Comment: can you help me out with this issue https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378572/custom-post-type-not-showing-in-xml-sitemap

Comment: @user9437856 there's no overlap between this question/answer and that one